# How to reduce/flatten an array of union type objects with serde_json?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I am trying to find an efficient way to deserialize the following kind of JSON data:

```
{
    "filters": [
        {
            "filterType": "MIN_FILTER",
            "min": 2
        },
        {
            "filterType": "MAX_FILTER",
            "max": 10
        },
        {
            "filterType": "PRIORITY_FILTER",
            "priority": "High"
        }
    ]
}
```

Into something like this:

```
{
    "filters": {
        "min": 2,
        "max:": 10,
        "priority": "High"
    }
}
```

I just began to learn Rust and Serde but the best I could come up so far is this custom Deserializer implementation that first deserializes every filter into a generic one which contains all possible fields with `Option` values:

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Object {
    filters: Filters,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Filters {
    min: u32,
    max: u32,
    priority: String,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Filters {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        #[derive(Deserialize)]
        pub struct GenericFilter {
            #[serde(rename = "filterType")]
            filter_type: String,
            priority: Option<String>,
            min: Option<u32>,
            max: Option<u32>,
        }

        let filters = Vec::<GenericFilter>::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        let mut priority: Option<&String> = None;
        let mut min: Option<u32> = None;
        let mut max: Option<u32> = None;

        for item in filters.iter() {
            match item.filter_type.as_str() {
                "PRIORITY_FILTER" => priority = item.priority.as_ref(),
                "MIN_FILTER" => min = item.min,
                "MAX_FILTER" => max = item.max,
                _ => (),
            }
        }

        Ok(Filters {
            priority: priority.unwrap().to_owned(),
            min: min.unwrap(),
            max: max.unwrap(),
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let json = r#"
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "filterType": "MIN_FILTER",
                    "min": 2
                },
                {
                    "filterType": "MAX_FILTER",
                    "max": 10
                },
                {
                    "filterType": "PRIORITY_FILTER",
                    "priority": "High"
                }
            ]
        }
    "#;

    println!(
        "Deserialized = {:#?}",
        serde_json::from_str::<Object>(&json)
    );
}
```

This just doesn't feel right and maybe someone has a better solution for this? :)

Comment: For one thing, might wanna try `match` instead of 3 if statements. Also, those 3 if statements should really be if-elseif-else :)

Comment: Really good points. I've updated my solution with your pattern matching approach, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the deserialization and the construction of the actual data. Deserialize a `Vec<GenericFilter>`, then have a separate function to construct `Filters` from it.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your suggestion but that would mean, that more memory is allocated to store the whole Vec<GenericFilter> and the Filters struct right? Maybe it would be better if I somehow try to implement a Visitor like this example: https://serde.rs/stream-array.html to avoid buffering entirely?

Comment: @chrigu You already allocate a `Vec<GenericFilter>`. I just suggest that the conversion won't be part of deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [internally `enum` representation](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#internally-tagged) with a tag set on `filterType` and use a "proxy" deserializer for the `Object` structure as below:

```
extern crate anyhow; // 1.0.69
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use anyhow::anyhow;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::convert::TryFrom;


#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(try_from = "ObjectDeserializer")]
pub struct Object {
    filters: Filters,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Filters {
    min: u32,
    max: u32,
    priority: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct ObjectDeserializer {
    filters: Vec<Filter>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "filterType")]
enum Filter {
    #[serde(rename = "PRIORITY_FILTER")]
    Priority{ priority: String },
    #[serde(rename = "MIN_FILTER")]
    Min { min: u32 },
    #[serde(rename = "MAX_FILTER")]
    Max { max: u32 },
}

impl TryFrom<ObjectDeserializer> for Object {
    type Error = anyhow::Error;
    fn try_from(obj: ObjectDeserializer) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let (mut min, mut max, mut priority) = (None, None, None);

        for filter in obj.filters {
            match filter {
                Filter::Min{ min: m } => min = Some(m),
                Filter::Max{ max: m } => max = Some(m),
                Filter::Priority { priority: p } => priority = Some(p),
            }
        }
        
        let filters = Filters {
            min: min.ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("missing `min` filter"))?,
            max: max.ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("missing `max` filter"))?,
            priority: priority.ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("missing `priority` filter"))?
        };
        
        Ok(Self { filters })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let json = r#"
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "filterType": "MIN_FILTER",
                    "min": 2
                },
                {
                    "filterType": "MAX_FILTER",
                    "max": 10
                },
                {
                    "filterType": "PRIORITY_FILTER",
                    "priority": "High"
                }
            ]
        }
    "#;

    println!(
        "Deserialized = {:#?}",
        serde_json::from_str::<Object>(&json)
    );
}
```

I used `anyhow` arbitrarily for the example and and the light error handling is on purpose because I don't know your complete structures and use cases ;)

EDIT: you can also flatten the `Filters` structure directly:

```
extern crate anyhow; // 1.0.69
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use anyhow::anyhow;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::convert::TryFrom;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(try_from = "Object")]
pub struct Filters {
    min: u32,
    max: u32,
    priority: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Object {
    filters: Vec<Filter>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "filterType")]
enum Filter {
    #[serde(rename = "PRIORITY_FILTER")]
    Priority{ priority: String },
    #[serde(rename = "MIN_FILTER")]
    Min { min: u32 },
    #[serde(rename = "MAX_FILTER")]
    Max { max: u32 },
}

impl TryFrom<Object> for Filters {
    type Error = anyhow::Error;
    fn try_from(obj: Object) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let (mut min, mut max, mut priority) = (None, None, None);

        for filter in obj.filters {
            match filter {
                Filter::Min{ min: m } => min = Some(m),
                Filter::Max{ max: m } => max = Some(m),
                Filter::Priority { priority: p } => priority = Some(p),
            }
        }
        
        let filters = Filters {
            min: min.ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("missing `min` filter"))?,
            max: max.ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("missing `max` filter"))?,
            priority: priority.ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("missing `priority` filter"))?
        };
        
        Ok(filters )
    }
}

fn main() {
    let json = r#"
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "filterType": "MIN_FILTER",
                    "min": 2
                },
                {
                    "filterType": "MAX_FILTER",
                    "max": 10
                },
                {
                    "filterType": "PRIORITY_FILTER",
                    "priority": "High"
                }
            ]
        }
    "#;

    println!(
        "Deserialized = {:#?}",
        serde_json::from_str::<Filters>(&json)
    );
}
```